# Review skip - bug or feature?

Tags: bug, review-queues

When I'm reviewing new posts, etc., and I come across something that I'm not sure about, I decide to skip it.

But there are no further posts coming up to be reviewed, although it shows that there are *n* number of reviews left.

Is this a 'punishment' for skipping, or is it a bug?

One last thing I can think of, but unsure, is that others are editing (all of) the remaining posts?

Can someone help me out on this, as I obviously won't use skip anymore if it's a punishment?

Comment: How is not showing you an item you stated you didn't want to review over and over again a punishment?

Comment: I did not mean the same items, but no items at all afterwards, let's say there are 10 posts waiting for reviews, I do the first one and skip the second one. After skipping the second, it says there are no items to be reviewed.

Comment: @Alex, that means the other items have been reviewed already.

Comment: Then the other 8 items were reviewed by other users, or kicked out of the review system for another reason (resolved outside of review in some way).

Comment: Thanks @Servy, it was one of my thoughts, but the confirmation is great.

Comment: Also, the number of pending items for each queue shown on the main review page has a lot of lag. That started after a site update a few weeks ago. You can often click on a queue that shows 0 pending items, and get a whole bunch to review. Or the opposite, a queue shows a significant number of pending items, but when you click on it there's (almost) nothing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is by design. The ones you skipped are still in the queue, still have to be reviewed, but since you skipped them, they're not visible to you.

Just to clarify: this is not a "punishment". You certainly should not feel discouraged from pressing the "skip" button. If you're not absolutely sure on how to handle a review, just skip it.

Comment: Cheers for the help

Comment: I think you meant "SHOULDN'T feel discouraged..."?

Comment: worth adding that one can revisit the skipped review items, see explanation of this feature at MSE: [Can our Review History also list the items we have skipped?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234909/165773) _"There's now a `show skipped reviews` checkbox and link to `my review history`. The checkbox enables toggling skipped reviews on a history page. The link takes you to your own review history. These options are now available for **all review queues**..."_

Answer (score 7):

This is not a bug.  Keep in mind that there are several thousand users here, and some of the easier queue's to empty are the queues that require the lowest amount of reputation in order to review.  Those queues get hit pretty quickly, so fast in fact that sometimes you'll see a number at the top and by the time you click the button they've *all* been reviewed already.  Of course, any reviews you skip will be subtracted from the number of available review items, so that will decrease your number.

However, please keep in mind that **you're doing it right**.  If you don't understand a review item, you should **always** skip it.  We want accurate reviews, not fast reviews.  The people who just quickly click the "Accept" button hoping to gain a badge more quickly will ultimately fail audits and have their reviewing privilidges suspended or revoked.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I did not realize that it can be revoked, but sounds logical to me.